# instanceof equivalent for a string-represented classname

Tags: php

I'm looking for a functionality, in the example below called "theFunctionILookFor", that will make the code work.

```
$myClassName = "someName";
$parentOrInterfaceName = "someParent";
if (theFunctionILookFor($myClassName)) {
    echo "is parent";
}
```

Edit: I try to avoid instantiating the class just to perform this check. I would like to be able to pass 2 string parameters to the checking function

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Looks like this is my answer: `is_subclass_of`

It can accept both parameters as strings

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php

Comment: Note that `is_subclass_of` check for children only and won't match if given class is the same as second parameter:

`class MyClass {} var_dump(is_subclass_of('MyClass', 'MyClass')); var_dump(is_subclass_of(new MyClass(), 'MyClass'));`

Result: 
`boolean false boolean false`

Comment: You can also use `is_a()` and pass in `TRUE` as the third parameter to allow strings.

Comment: The answer was answered by @Unsigned

Comment: It worths noting that  `is_subclass_of` triggers autoloader in case the classname does not exist. It doesn't if the third parameter is `false`, but then you can't provide a string as first parameter.

Comment: This answer is slightly incorrect. The correct answer to match logical equivalent of `instanceof` is `is_a()` with `true` passed as third parameter as pointed in the comments. **The `is_subclass_of()` does not match self unlike `instanceof` and `is_a()`.**

Answer (score 9):

Try `is_subclass_of()`.  It can accept both parameters as strings. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php

Answer (score 4):

Using the [Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), you can [construct a ReflectionClass object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php) using the name of the class as well as an object.

Answer (score 3):

You might use this?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php

From the page:

> **get_parent_class**
>
> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>   get_parent_class — Retrieves the parent class
>   name for object or class
>
> **Description**
>
> ```
> string get_parent_class ([ mixed $object ] )
> ```
>
> Retrieves the parent
>   class name for object or class.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but still for future reference, you can use the functions `is_a` and `is_subclass_of` to accomplish this in a more efficient way. 
No need to instantiate anything, you can just pass your string like:

```
if (is_subclass_of($myObject, 'SomeClass')) // is_a(...)
  echo "yes, \$myObject is a subclass of SomeClass\n";
else
  echo "no, \$myObject is not a subclass of SomeClass\n";
```

PHP Docs:

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `is_a()` and `is_subclass_of()` are not equivalent. A class is not a subclass of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's old question, but problem still is actual, here, below, the best solution I've found

```
class ProductAttributeCaster
{
    public function cast(mixed $value): mixed
    {
        if ($value instanceof ($this->castTo())) {
            // do stuff
        }

        return $value;
    }

    function castTo(): string
    {
        return ProductAttribute::class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that `instanceof` is a lot faster and more clear to read.

`instanceof` does not work on strings, because it can be used as a "identifier" for a class:

```
 $temp = 'tester';
 $object  = new sub();
 var_dump($object instanceof $temp); //prints "true" on php 5.3.8

 class tester{}

 class sub extends \tester{

 }
```

Also, it works on interfaces - you just need a variable to contain the absolute class name (including namespace, if you want to be 100% sure).

Comment: Works with variables but not string literals ( ... `instanceof "tester"`). Trying it now.

Comment: OP clearly asked about the situation where a) there is not object, b) the object shouldn't/musn't be instantiated. This doesn't answer the question as it currently stands.

Comment: Also note that you cannot blindly instantiate an object. For example, if the class to be tested is RAII interface to SQL database, the constructor would need to create a database connection and you should definitely not do that blindly. Use `is_a()` instead with third parameter set to `true`. As the original question already mentions `instanceof` trying to suggest it as an answer to the question provides no value, hence -1.